# PHP: Allowed memory size of ... bytes exhausted

Tags: php, laravel

I'm trying to run `artisan make:controller`.

I'm getting an issue with:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Allowed memory size of
```

I tried to increase size of `memory-limit` but it didn't work. I tried larger values and -1. This does not seem to be the best option. It seems I may  have a memory leak, but I don't know how to find it. Does it have something to do with garbage collection?

I'm not able to run `artisan` code but getting:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted  
(tried to allocate 65536 bytes) in \laravel\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Console\GeneratorCommand.php on line 85  
PHP Fatal error:  Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted  
(tried to allocate 65536 bytes) in \laravel\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Support\Manager.php on line 85
```

Comment: Not a solution, but a general rule of thumb. Only ever increase `memory-limit` if you have exhausted all other options. Seems your limit is already very high at 128MB, what will happen if 10 people visit your site at once, do you have 1GB of spare RAM for when this might happen? A high memory limit is a DoS attack waiting to happen.

Comment: I abandoned this project. I got it again a few days ago and couldnt find why it was being caused but undid what I did. This removed the error. I recommend using git so you can revert to a previous state.

Answer (score 0):

you may need to check circular reference between class autoload

Comment: i have tried to `dump-autoload`. But still getting the problem.

Answer (score -1):

Are you sure, you set the memory limit on the correct php.ini ?

The following command should help you.

```
php -d memory_limit=256M artisan make:controller
```

Comment: This didnt improve it. got the following `vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Console\GeneratorCommand.php:85
    81|      * @return string
    82|      */
    83|     protected function qualifyClass($name)
    84|     {
  > 85|         $name = ltrim($name, '\\/');
    86| 
    87|         $rootNamespace = $this->rootNamespace();
    88| 
    89|         if (Str::startsWith($name, $rootNamespace)) {`

Comment: can you remove the vender folder from your project and try again ?

Comment: Removed 'vendor' folder. Then ran `artisan`. It requires autoload. So i then ran `composer install` and the same memory limit issue returned.